# ASP.NET Core Web App: How to get a client's certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, https

My goal is to obtain the public key associated with a particular browser's/client's certificate info at runtime, and eventually store these public keys.

---

Here's a high-level example.

**Server**: ASP.NET Core Web App, hosted in Azure

**Device1**: a Chrome browser, running on a Windows 10 laptop

**Device2**: a Firefox browser, running on a Google Pixel 2

---

- **Device1** makes a GET request to **Server**; some code running on **Server** gets the public key of the cert used by Chrome; the public key is "1122"
- **Device2** makes a GET request to **Server**; some code running on **Server** gets the public key of the cert used by Firefox; the public key is "3344"

---

## What code do I need to write to get "1122" and "3344"?

I've looked at the **X509Certificate2** class, but all the examples I've seen are kind of confusing, and don't accomplish what I want (also, I've *never* messed with SSL certs in code before). I've also seen the **HttpClientCertificate** class, however I can't figure out how to use that class. I feel like there's a library out there that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Have you tried `this.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate` in your controller? Currently have never ending VS installer updates going so i haven't been able to test this

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 2.0... I tried `this.Request.ClientCertificate`, but there was no property for ClientCertificate :(

Comment: So, I got my code working; I just had to flip a switch in the Azure portal in the SSL settings. However, now I'm getting "403 Forbidden: Client Certificate Required" message in Firefox. Maybe I'm using the wrong kind of client cert?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, the client certificate can be accessed via `httpContext.Connection.ClientRequest`.